# Find the numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with its $\mathbf{QR}$ factorization:
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&-3&8&-1\\
-4&-3&-2&-2\\
2&4&1&3\\
2&4&16&1
\end{array}\right] =
\left[ \begin {array}{rrrr} 1/5&-4/5&2/5&2/5\\  -4/5
&1/5&2/5&2/5\\  2/5&2/5&-1/5&4/5\\  
2/5&2/5&4/5&-1/5\end {array} \right]
\left[ \begin {array}{rrrr} 5&5&10&3\\  0&5&0&2
\\  0&0&15&-1\\  0&0&0&1\end {array}
 \right] =
\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}
$$
Which means that $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{Q} \leftarrow \mathcal{A}} = \mathbf{R}$ for the bases $\mathcal{A} = \{\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{a}_3, \mathbf{a}_4\}$ og $\mathcal{Q} = \{\mathbf{q}_1, \mathbf{q}_2, \mathbf{q}_3, \mathbf{q}_4\}$.

I then need to find the numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4$  such that
$\lambda_1 \mathbf{a}_1 + \lambda_2 \mathbf{a}_2 + \lambda_3 \mathbf{a}_3 + \lambda_4 \mathbf{a}_4 = \mathbf{q}_1 + \mathbf{q}_2 + \mathbf{q}_3 - \lambda_4 \mathbf{q}_4$.

My first thought was to just add $\lambda_4 \mathbf{q}_4$ to the LHS of the equation and then solve it as a standard matrix equation $\mathbf{Ax}={\mathbf{b}}$. This gives
$$
\left[ \begin {array}{c} -2/15\\ 1/5
\\ 1/15\\ 0\end {array} \right]
$$ which does add up but I do not think that this is the right way/"best" way to solve this. I have the feeling that some of the $\lambda s$ might also be free variables, maybe $\lambda_4$. So how would you find the numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4$  such that
$\lambda_1 \mathbf{a}_1 + \lambda_2 \mathbf{a}_2 + \lambda_3 \mathbf{a}_3 + \lambda_4 \mathbf{a}_4 = \mathbf{q}_1 + \mathbf{q}_2 + \mathbf{q}_3 - \lambda_4 \mathbf{q}_4$ using the knowledge of $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{Q} \leftarrow \mathcal{A}} = \mathbf{R}$ and the $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{QR}$ relation?

***Update:***
I have that 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\lambda_1\\
\lambda_2\\
\lambda_3\\
\lambda_4
\end{array}\right] =
\mathbf{A}^{-1}
\mathbf{Q}
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
1\\
1\\
-\lambda_4
\end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin {array}{c} -2/15+\lambda_{4}/3\\  1/5+
2/5\,\lambda_{4}\\  1/15-\lambda_{4}/15
\\  -\lambda_{4}\end {array} \right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-\frac{2}{15}\\
\frac{1}{5}\\
\frac{1}{15}\\
0
\end{array}\right]
+
\lambda_4
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{5}\\
-\frac{1}{15}\\
-1
\end{array}\right]
$$

But wut? How can $\lambda_4 = -\lambda_4$? This result does not make sense to me :/ Is this right and if so how should I understand it?